# node.js - more than 2 byte hex number

Tags: node.js, hex, 32-bit

I'd like to print into a console 4-byte number represented in hexadecimal like so:

```
console.log('\x5050');
```

but clearly it behaves like 2-byte because it outputs

```
P50
```

P is 0x50 and then it just prints out remaining 50 as is. How do I make my program to look at it as a whole 32bit number, not 8bit?

Thank you!

Comment: `console.log('\u5050')`? BTW `'\x5050'` is string, not a number.

Comment: You could read about js escape sequences here [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) `\xXX` encodes latin-1 character

Answer (score 0):

First, `0x5050` is **2 byte** not 4. Literal `\x50` represents one byte because it takes two hexadecimal digits to represent an 8-bit number. Second, `\x` literal encodes only one byte, so you should use it like `console.log('\x50\x50')`.

Answer (score 0):

The `'\xXX'` notation in a string is used to convert the hexadecimal value to an ASCII character:

```
console.log('\x61');  // a
```

It's just a char in a string.

```
console.log('What\x27s up\x3F')  // What's up?
```

You can accomplish what you want with the `0xXX` notation and the `parseInt()` method if it is a string representation:

```
console.log(parseInt('0x5050', 16))  // 20560
console.log(parseInt('5050', 16))  // 20560
console.log(0x5050)  // 20560
```